# React native react-native-paper button with greater height

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, react-native-paper

[image]

I'm using `react-native-paper`, I would like to make a button with bigger dimensions than normal, as seen in the gif.

I've tried using both `height` and `padding`, but both don't work properly.

What you see in the gif is the example with padding.

only way to click is in the center, in other places the event does not happen.

Can you give me a hand?

```
<Button
          mode="contained"
          labelStyle={{ color: Colors.white }}
          style={{ padding: 30 }}
          onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
          Start
        </Button>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for the above?

Answer (score 7):

**YOU CAN USE**

```
contentStyle
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
<Button
  onPress={() => {}}
  style={styles.completeFormButton}
  styleText={styles.completeFormButtonText}
  contentStyle={{ // <--- HERE-----
    paddingVertical: 10,
  }}
  preset="outlined"
/>
```

`react-native-papper` has these three props to pass styles

**contentStyle**
Type: StyleProp
Style of button's inner content. Use this prop to apply custom height and width and to set the icon on the right with flexDirection: 'row-reverse'.

**style**
Type: StyleProp

**labelStyle**
Type: StyleProp
Style for the button text.

[View documentation react native paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html#contentStyle)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a touchablehighlight view around the button and call the same onPress function. something like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 70,
            width: 110,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Button
            mode="contained"
            labelStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
            onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
            Start
          </Button>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
```